# Is it possible using git to create a branch for existing files?

Tags: symfony, github

This might be  a simple question but I have project on git and I am tasked with revamping it. So I started writing a bundle in Symfony which I got at a good state. Is there a way now to make this a branch of git? I probably should have created a branch, deleted everything and then started my project in the empty branch right? So can I do the same now, create a branch, delete all files and just copy my files there? I think as long as they stay in the src folder it should be ok, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout -b new_branch_name
```

A new branch will be created and all your files will be moved there.

This assumes that you have already created a clone to your remote repository and the new_branch_name will be used when pushing.

After this new files can be copied and deleted from where this command was run. Then you must run:

```
git add *
```

This will add all files from this folder and subfolder that are to be tracked. Then you must commit them to be maintained in history:

```
git commit -a -m "Some message saying why you committed them"
```

Then you can push them to your remote repository:

```
git push Nameofremote Nameofbranch
```

In the case above it would be the following assuming you didn't rename remote or switch head:

```
git push origin new_branch_name
```

Used [This](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) to help me along.

Comment: Doesn't that just checkout all the files from the master and move them to where I run that command? I want to make my existing files on my system a branch. @Cristian

Comment: @shayster01 Yes, but it also leaves the files you've changed as-is, unstaged and uncommitted. Once you've made and checked out your new branch, you can commit your new files to the branch like normal.

Comment: So both the master and the file I had there will be there and then I can just delete the unnecessary master files? @sjagr

Comment: @shayster01 Why are the master files unnecessary? Unless the files are no longer necessary for the entire project, you shouldn't be deleting anything.

Comment: I am revamping the files and none of them will be used. The current master files are in production but not relevant for my project. One more question, by that command how does it know which master file I am using?